# change() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of an input and display a tooltip if the value is equal to 12. I first display the value of an input in a `<p>`, as that's what the designers want, then I get the value in jQuery.

My idea was to make an `if` statement, and say that if the value is equal to 12, I'll display the tooltip. If the value changes and is not 12 anymore, I'll hide the tooltip. I use WordPress for the project.

```js
$(function(ready) {
  var txtInput = $('.person-range-value').html();
  txtInput.change(function() {
    console.log(txtInput);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="person-range-value c-red">4</p>

<div class="person-range-element">
  4
  <input class="person-range slider-range" id="nombre" type="range" min="4" max="12" value="4" /> 12
</div>
```

I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: txtInput.change is not a function

Why's that ? jQuery is included already and works properly ( the whole JS file is written with jQuery and it works fine, the error definitely comes from my function ).

Thanks !

Comment: The `.html()` doesn't make sense. Strings don't have a `change` method.

Comment: `txtInput` is a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `html`, because you need to attach a `change` *event* handler to the `input` element.

Also, you need to change your `selector` to

```
$('.person-range-value input')
```

because you need to *target* the your `input` *DOM* element.

```js
$(function (ready) {
    var txtInput = $('.person-range-element input');
    txtInput.change(function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="person-range-element">
        4
       <input class="person-range slider-range" id="nombre" type="range" min="4" max="12" value="4"/> 
       12
</div>
```

Comment: @MaelLandrin, you're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding change method in html:

```
$('.person-range-value').html()
```

Also, you cannot bind the change event on non-input elements. You must fire this event in input elements. So, you may do like:

```
var txtInput = $('.person-range'); // your input field
txtInput.change(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  // or,
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I forgot to write the <p> tag, but .person-range-value is a <p> tag, I need to get either the value inside the <p>, or the value of the input. I tried getting the value of the input with .val(), but it only got me the attribute value, which is set to 4.

Comment: Only input elements fire change event.